# In cvs diff I want to see author name and date of files having difference

Tags: unix, diff, cvs, wincvs

How can I get the author name and date of the different files, when I do a cvs diff.
M using wincvs on windows 2.1.1.1(build 1). I can also do it on unix server through command line.
thx

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless this information appears in the source (which it shouldn't, unless you want a conflict at every merge). You need to use other cvs commands for this; cvs log comes to mind, but it's been a while. You could always write a script or batch file which displays the changes' log entiries and diffs, though.